# How to make a rank widget in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

All:

This is probably an old question but I can not find an easy answer:

What I want is to design a 5 stars rank widget, user mouseover/click one star, and all stars before it(and itself) highlighted, if user did not click on star and move out, it will just remain previous rank, otherwise, change rank. I wonder how can I implement this AngularJS?

```
<vp-rank></vp-rank>


<script type="text/ng-template" id="#ranktmplate">
    <div class="rank">
        <img class="star" ng-repeat="s in [1,2,3,4,5] track by $index" ng-src="{{getStar(s)}}" ng-mouseover="changeRank(s)">
    </div>
</script>
```

(function(){

```
        var app = angular.module("vp", []);
        app.directive("vpRank", function(){
            return {
                restrict: "AE",
                scope:{},
                templateUrl: "#ranktmplate",
                controller: function($scope){
                    $scope.rank = 1;
                    $scope.getStar = function(idx){
                        return +idx<=$scope.rank?"public/images/star.png":"public/images/star_blnk.png";
                    }
                    $scope.changeRank = function(rnk){
                        $scope.rank = rnk;
                    }
                },
                link: function(scope, EL, attrs){

                }
            };
        });

    })();
```

Right now, this directive can highlight according to user mouse over, I do not know **how to implement reserving previous rank if use did not click and mouseout.**

Thanks

Comment: why are you changing the rank on mouse-over? don't you want to change rank on click only? on mouse-over i would think you'd want to simply show the class toggle to the rank, then on click save the rank.

Comment: @DaveBriand Sorry for my poor expression, when mouse over, there needs to be a "preview" mode, the star will get highlighted to show what is the rank the user gonna give if user click. If user does not click and move mouse out, the preview mode ends and restore to the rank before user mouseover.

Comment: Have you tried removing $scope.rank = 1 and storing current rank in an element data attribute?

Comment: why re-invent the wheel when there are all sorts of ratings modules readily available

Comment: @charliefl  To learn how it works and be able to control it according to customization requirement.